# Asymptotic value of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

It is well known that $F_n\sim\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Does someone know a better estimate?  With proof please.

I'm trying to calculate the following limit:

Let $u_1=1, u_2=C, u_3=C$ and

$$
u_n=\frac{C^{F_{n-1}}}{2^{F_{n-3}}3^{F_{n-4}}\cdots(n-2)^{F_1}}
$$ for $n\geq 4$, where

$$
C=\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log k}{\phi^k}\right).
$$

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n$.

Comment: Did you at least read the wikipedia article? It gives a closed form expression.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Comment: Yes, I did. But I'm looking for a better asymptotic value.

Comment: What can be a better asymptotic value than the literal closed form?

Comment: I need calculate a limit, so closed form it is not good in this case.

Comment: The error term (the other one in the explicit expression) decreases exponentially.  That is hard to beat.  What is the main problem?

Comment: Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{F_{n+1-k}}{\phi^{n+1}}\log k$.

Comment: @bob, using the asymptotic $F_n = \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}} + O(\phi^{-n})$ it's possible to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi^{-n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} F_{n+1-k} \log k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log k}{\phi^k} \approx 0.5203\ 1109\ 0193.$$  Would you like me to write an answer outlining the argument?

Comment: @AntonioVargas thank you, in this case $\frac{\log u_{n+2}}{\phi^{n+1}}\rightarrow 0$, what can be said about $\lim u_n$?

Comment: @bob, By my calculations $$u_n = n^{\large -A(1+o(1))},$$ where $A \approx 3.15667$ can be expressed in terms of the golden ratio.  Hence $u_n \to 0$.  The calculations were a bit tricky so I'll have to clean them up before I can post an answer.  What's the origin of this problem?

Comment: @AntonioVargas, thank you, take your time. The problem arise in my investigation about sequences and Fibonacci numbers, C is the critical value, we are considering the equivalent sequence $b_{n+2}=b_{n+1}b_{n}/n$, for $b_2 > C$ and $b_2 < C$ we can find $\lim b_n$.

Comment: Why all the down-votes for this question?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, the original question was arguably a little unfocused but it was greatly improved in an edit.  Now it's a perfectly good question and, as you note, definitely doesn't deserve all these downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we let

$$
a_n = 2^{\large F_{n-3}} 3^{\large F_{n-4}} \cdots (n-2)^{\large F_{1}} = \prod_{k=2}^{n-2} k^{\large F_{n-1-k}}
$$

then

$$
\log a_n = \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} F_{n-1-k} \log k. \tag{1}
$$

Using Binet's formula

$$
F_m = \frac{\varphi^m - (-\varphi)^{-m}}{\sqrt{5}},
$$

$(1)$ becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{5} \log a_n &= \varphi^{n-1} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \varphi^{-k} \log k - (-\varphi)^{1-n} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} (-\varphi)^{k} \log k \\
&= b_n + c_n,
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
b_n = \varphi^{n-1} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \varphi^{-k} \log k \qquad \text{and} \qquad c_n = -(-\varphi)^{1-n} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} (-\varphi)^{k} \log k. \tag{2}
$$

The sum in $b_n$ converges as $n \to \infty$, so we'll rewrite it as

$$
b_n = \varphi^{n-1} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k} \log k - \varphi^{n-1} \sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k}\log k. \tag{3}
$$

> **Lemma 1:**
>   $$
> \sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k}\log k = \frac{\varphi^{2-n}\log n}{\varphi - 1} + O\left(\frac{\varphi^{-n}}{n}\right). \tag{4}
> $$
>   *Idea of the proof:* Split the sum at $k=\frac{3}{2}n$.  For the sum over $k \geq \frac{3}{2} n$ use the rough estimate $\log k < k$, and for the sum over $n-1 \leq k < \frac{3}{2} n$ expand $\log k$ in series about the point $k = n-1$.
>
> **Lemma 2:**
>   $$
> \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} (-\varphi)^{k}\log k = \frac{-(-\varphi)^{n-1}\log n}{\varphi + 1} + O\left(\frac{\varphi^{n}}{n}\right). \tag{5}
> $$
>   *Idea of the proof:* Split the sum at $k=\frac{1}{2}n$ and proceed as in Lemma 1.

Combining $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ we obtain

$$
\sqrt{5} \log a_n = \varphi^{n-1} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k} \log k + \left(\frac{1}{\varphi + 1} - \frac{\varphi}{\varphi - 1}\right) \log n + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

Since $\frac{1}{\varphi + 1} - \frac{\varphi}{\varphi - 1} = -\sqrt{5}$ we can rewrite this as

$$
\log a_n = \frac{\varphi^{n-1}}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k} \log k - \log n + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

Exponentiating this yields

$$
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{1}{n} \exp\left(\frac{\varphi^{n-1}}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k} \log k\right)\left[1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \exp\left(F_{n-1} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \varphi^{-k} \log k\right)\left[1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{C^{\large F_{n-1}}}{n} \left[1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right],
\end{align}
$$

where in the second line we used the estimate $F_n = \frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5}} + O(\varphi^{-n})$.  Finally we have

$$
u_n = \frac{C^{\large F_{n-1}}}{a_n} = n \left[1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right] = n + O(1).
$$

Comment: Clearly my initial calculations I based my comment off of were wrong :)

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you so much.

Comment: +1 BTW, expanding your method, $u_n$ seems to have an asymptotic expansion: $$u_n \asymp n + 1 - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{8}{n^2} - \frac{52}{n^3} + \frac{452}{n^4}-\frac{4860}{n^5} + \cdots$$